# Is $\ell^1$ isomorphic to $L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Can there be a continuous linear map, with a continuous inverse, from
$l^{1}$ to $L^{1}(m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on the
unit interval $\left[0,1\right]?$

My thinking to this should be No. In $l^{1}$, we have a special property
that weak convergence is actually equivalent to norm convergence;
proven using a "gliding hump argument". This is certainly impossible
in $L^{1}(m)$. A continuous linear map with continuous inverse is
essentially a homeomorphism between the two spaces; so it should preserve
norm convergence. I'm just wondering if my reasoning is correct and
also if there are any resources out there that I can understand these
ideas better.

Comment: Two nitpicks: 1. weak convergence should be weak sequential convergence. 2. (more important) how do you *define* weak convergence intrinsically? The pre-dual of a Banach space is not uniquely determined. But if you're happy with arguing with pre-duals, notice that $l^1$ is a dual space, while $L^1$ isn't (the unit ball doesn't have *any* extremal points).

Comment: See also [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97126/5363) for a discussion of $\ell^p$ and $L^p$.

Answer (score 6):

The property you are referring to is called [**Schur's property,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property) and it's preserved by isomorphisms (and this can be used to
distinguish between $\ell^1$ and $L^1$).

Comment: oh, boy. I still manage to mix up weak and weak$^{\ast}$ convergence...

Comment: @Theo Buehler : your comment indeed seemed off-topic to me, but since it was a "nitpick", I didn't dare to question it... maybe you could edit the question title, setting it to something more meaningful and clear of "Basic Functional Analysis Question". Probably "Is $\ell^1$ isomorphic to $L^1$" would fit, or something similar...

Comment: Done, following your suggestion. Oh, well. Everyone goofs from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

NO, they are not isomorphic.  My favorite off-beat reason:  $l^1$ has the Radon-Nikodym Property and $L^1$ doesn't.
reference: Diestel & Uhl, *Vector Measures*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more answer.

Every closed subspace of $\ell_1$ contains a copy of $\ell_1$ but $L_1$ contains a copy of $\ell_2$ - for example take the closed linear span of the Rademacher system and apply Khinchine's inequality.