# How do you prove that $\ell_p$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_q$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I guess that for all  $1\le p,q<\infty $, such that $p\ne q$ , the spaces $\ell_p$ and $\ell_q$ are not isomorphic, but how do you prove this?

Comment: See the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97126/if-1-leq-p-infty-then-show-that-lp0-1-and-ell-p-are-not-topologic

Comment: I wrote a proof of the result mentioned by David Mitra:
"In fact no infinite dimensional subspace of ℓp isomorphically embeds in ℓq for p≠q, 1≤p,q<∞", in great detail, with no need to mention compact maps. It's in portuguese though -- let me know if you're interested, in that case I could translate it. Or maybe you could give Google Translator a try ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand on David's comment, since the question he links to is not the same one that you ask: a theorem of Pitt (which *is* mentioned in the question Linked to) tells us that when $1\leq p < q <\infty$, every bounded linear map from $\ell^q$ to $\ell^p$ is compact. In particular, since the only Banach spaces with compact unit ball are finite-dimensional, there can be no bounded linear bijection between the two spaces.

Showing that naturally occurring Banach spaces are non-isomorphic can be surprisingly difficult; I don't know a simpler approach in this case, although one could probably rig up a direct argument by using ingredients from the proof of Pitt's theorem.

More information and some other non_-isomorphism results can be found in a [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79713/lp-mathbbr-vs-lq-mathbbr/79892#79892) of Bill Johnson.

Comment: In fact no infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ isomorphically embeds in $\ell_q$ for $p\ne q$, $1\le p,q<\infty$.