# $\ell^p$ is not isometric to $\ell^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The problem is this: if $1\le p<q<\infty$ then $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are not isometric (as Banach spaces).
This is an exercise but I'd like to see an elegant proof.

Comment: They aren't even isomorphic to each other. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99086/how-do-you-prove-that-ell-p-is-not-isomorphic-to-ell-q/99093#99093). I do not know of a simpler argument showing they aren't isometric.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for the downvote. I know this fact is well-known and that Bertrand's postulate immediately follows from the Prime Number Theorem, but this does not imply that this question isn't interesting on its own.

Comment: I find it interesting as well. I imagine someone wanted you to "show your work". (Where did you see this by the way?)

Comment: I wonder if you can compute the modulus of convexity for these spaces... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_convexity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Remark**   As is well-known, the Banach spaces $c_0$ and $\ell^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ are mutually non-isomorphic, as a consequence of Pitt's theorem. See Corollary 2.1.6 in [Albiac-Kalton's book](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Topics_in_Banach_Space_Theory.html?id=g9nj7dcfNhoC&redir_esc=y). It seems a bit easier to prove the weaker result saying that the $\ell^p$ spaces are mutually non-isometric.

Note that $\ell^1$ is not strictly convex, while [Clarkson's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities) show that $\ell^p$ is strictly convex for every $1<p<\infty$. So $\ell^1$ is not isometric to $\ell^p$ for any $1<p<\infty$. We could obtain the same conclusion using reflexivity or uniform convexity instead of strict convexity.

> Now assume there exist $1<p,q<\infty$ such that $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are isometric via some isometry $T$: $\|Tx\|_p=\|x\|_q$ for every $x\in \ell^q$. We need to show that $p=q$.

**Sketch**  An elementary manipulation of Clarkson's inequalities ([see here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1940-46-04/S0002-9904-1940-07207-6/) for a short proof by R.P. Boas) yields Claim 1 below. Claims 2,3,4 follow immediately. This allows us to rule out every case but $q=p$ and $q=p'$. So it only remains to check that $\ell^2$ is the only $\ell^p$ space which is isometric to its dual (i.e. Claim 5, essentially).

We will denote $p'$ the conjugate exponent associated with $p$, i.e. $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1 \iff p'=\frac{p}{p-1}$. Recall that the continuous dual $(\ell^p)'$ is isometric to $\ell^{p'}$ for every $1<p<\infty$.

> **Claim 1**   If $p\geq 2$, then $p'\leq q\leq p$.

**Proof**   For every $x,y \in \ell^q$, we have
$$
\big\| \frac{x+y}{2} \big\|_q^p+\big\| \frac{x-y}{2} \big\|_q^p=\big\| \frac{Tx+Ty}{2} \big\|_p^p+\big\| \frac{Tx-Ty}{2} \big\|_p^p
$$
$$
\leq \frac{\|Tx\|_p^p+\|Ty\|_p^p}{2}=\frac{\|x\|_q^p+\|y\|_q^p}{2}
$$
where we used Clarkson's inequality for $p\geq 2$. In particular, for $x=(1,1,0,\ldots)$ and $y=(1,-1,0,\ldots)$, this yields 
$$2=1+1\leq \frac{2^\frac{p}{q}+2^\frac{p}{q}}{2}=2^\frac{p}{q}\quad\Rightarrow\quad q\leq p$$
While for $x=(2,0,\ldots)$ and $y=(0,2,0,\ldots)$, we get
$$
2\cdot 2^\frac{p}{q}=2^\frac{p}{q}+2^\frac{p}{q} \leq \frac{2^p+2^p}{2}=2^p \quad\Rightarrow\quad p'=\frac{p}{p-1}\leq q
$$
Therefore we have $p'\leq q\leq p$. $\Box$

> **Claim 2**   If $p\leq 2$, then $p\leq q\leq p'$.

**Proof**   Taking the dual,  $\ell^p\simeq \ell^q$ yields an isometric isomorphism $\ell^{p'}\simeq \ell^{q'}$. Since $p'\geq 2$, Claim 1 applied to $p'$ implies $(p')'\leq q'\leq p'\iff p\leq q\leq p'$. $\Box$

> **Claim 3**   If $p$ and $q$ are both $\geq 2$ or both $\leq 2$, then $p=q$.

**Proof**   Assume $p,q\geq 2$. Applying Claim 1 to $p$ yields $q\leq p$, while applying it to $q$ gives $p\leq q$. Hence $p=q$. The case $p,q \leq 2$ follows from Claim 2 in a similar manner. Or you can just take the duals and conclude that $p'=q'$ since they are both $\geq 2$. $\Box$

> **Claim 4**   If $p\geq 2$ and $q\leq 2$, then $q=p'$.

**Proof**   By Claim 1 for $p$, we have $p'\leq q$. By Claim 2 for $q$, we get $p\leq q' \iff q\leq p'$. Hence $q=p'$. $\Box$

> **Claim 5**   If $\ell^p$ is isometric to $\ell^{p'}$, then $p=p'=2$.

**Proof**   Still pondering what the easiest argument could be...

[Edit by the OP: see [my answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2466604/24753), which should prove Claim 5 and finish the problem off.]

Comment: Nice! How do you rule out the case $p=q',q=p'$?

Comment: Just curious, is $\ell_{p}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 4):

Let me complete the accepted answer by showing that $\ell^p$ is not isometric to $\ell^q$ if $1<p<2$ and $2<q<\infty$. Fix $1<r<\infty$. I claim that

> **Claim 5'** The second derivative $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}\Big|_{t=0}$
>   exists for every $x\in\ell^r\setminus\{0\}$ and every $y\in\ell^r$ if and only if $r\ge 2$.

Clearly, the claim implies the first assertion and thus finishes the problem.

**Proof** If $r<2$ then we take $x:=e_1$, $y:=e_2$ and we see that the second derivative $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(1+|t|^r)^{1/r}\Big|_{t=0}$ does not exist. On the other hand, let $r\ge 2$: we claim that
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d}{dt}\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}\Big|_{t=0}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x'_ny_n=:A(x,y), \\ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}\Big|_{t=0}&=(r-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty x''_ny_n^2-\frac{(r-1)}{\|x\|}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x'_ny_n\Big)^2=:B(x,y),\end{aligned}$$
where $x'\in\ell^{r/(r-1)}$ and $x''\in\ell^{r/(r-2)}$ are defined by
$$x'_n:=\frac{|x_n|^{r-2}x_n}{\|x\|_{\ell^r}^{r-1}},\quad x''_n:=\frac{|x_n|^{r-2}}{\|x\|_{\ell^r}^{r-1}}.$$
Notice that $x'$ and $x''$ depend continuously on $x\neq 0$ (which is easily seen by dominated convergence) and $\|x'\|_{\ell^{r/(r-1)}}=1$, $\|x''\|_{\ell^{r/(r-2)}}=\|x\|_{\ell^r}^{-1}$. So, by the [generalized Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality), $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$ are continuous and satisfy $|A(x,y)|\le\|y\|_{\ell^r}$, $|B(x,y)|\le 2(r-1)\|x\|_{\ell^r}^{-1}\|y\|_{\ell^r}^2$.

These formulas are a straightforward computation if $x,y\in c_c$ ($c_c$ being the space of sequences where only finitely many terms are nonzero). In order to check that they are true in general, we observe that for $x,y\in c_c$
$$\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}=\|x\|_{\ell^r}+tA(x,y)+\int_0^t(t-s)B(x+sy,y)\,ds$$
(Taylor's expansion with remainder in integral form) and, by a density argument and dominated convergence, we see that this equation holds for all $x\in\ell^r\setminus\{0\}$ and all $y\in\ell^r$. Hence,
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d}{dt}\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}&=A(x,y)+\int_0^t B(x+sy,y)\,ds, \\ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\|x+ty\|_{\ell^r}\Big|_{t=0}&=B(x,y).\end{aligned}$$
This finishes the proof. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

*I think it should work.*

Suppose for definiteness $p < q$. Then $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$. Assume that an isometry exists $J: \ell^p \to \ell^q$. Then $J(\ell^p) \subset \ell^q$ and in particular $J(B_{\ell^p}) \subset B_{\ell^q}$, where $B_X$ is the unit ball of $X$. Let us choice $r >0$ s.t. $r B_{\ell^q} \subset J(B_{\ell^p})$ (such an $r$ must exist, since $J(B_{\ell^p})$ is nonempty). Being an isometry, $J$ is an isomorphism from $\ell^p$ onto $J(\ell^p)$, i.e. into $\ell_q$, so by Pitt's theorem it must be compact. But $J(B_{\ell^p})$ can't be compact, since $rB_{\ell^q}$ is not. Hence $J$ can't be an isometry.

**Remark 1.** Take with care! It seems to me that it works but wait for community peer-review!

**Remark 2.** It is well known that every Banach separable space is isometrically embedded into a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$, so we are correctly considering only the case $p,q < \infty$. The proof of this fact relies on the Hahn-Banach theorem; maybe one can adapt it to our case.

Comment: Most of users were aware of this proof. The problem is to find an *elementary* proof.

Comment: What do we extacly mean by "elementary"? A proof based only upon definitions? In my opinion, a proof is elementary if it involves only concepts usually taught in basic courses. In both senses, however, I agree that the demonstration I wrote is not elementary (but I believed we were looking for an "elegant" proof, that is not the same) and obviously I was expecting that a reasoning was widely known. (is too easy not to be!) :)

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: This answer is based on a (most probably) false assumption and so it is (most probably) wrong. See comments

Here's a partial answer which works when $p$ and $q$ are even integers. This extra assumption is used in the shaded area below.

If a linear isometry of $\ell^p$ onto $\ell^q$ existed, its restriction to the subspace 
$$\left\{ (x_1, x_2, 0, 0 \ldots)\ :\ x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\subset \ell^p$$
would yield a linear isometry of $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_p)$ onto $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_q)^{[1]}$. Therefore we only need to show that the latter cannot exist.

> Since $p$ is an even integer, the $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p$-unit
>   circle is an algebraic curve of degree $p$:  $$S_p=\left\{ (x_1, x_2)\
>  :\ x_1^p+x_2^p=1\right\}, $$ and any nonsingular linear operation
>   transforms it into an algebraic curve of the same degree. This rules
>   out the existence of a linear isometry of $(\mathbb{R}^2,
>  \lvert\cdot\rvert_p)$ onto $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_q)$
>   because such a mapping would transform $S_p$ into $S_q$ and the latter has degree $q$.

$^{[1]}$ Where $\lvert (x_1, x_2)\rvert_p=\left( \lvert x_1\rvert^p+\lvert x_2\rvert^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. $S_p$ is carried into a subset of $\sum |x_i|^q=1$: your answer seems to imply that actually its image is of the form $(0,\dots,x_m,0,\dots,x_n,0,\dots)$ (for two distinct $m<n$, which wlog are $1,2$) but why is it so?

Comment: @Mizar good catch!

Comment: @Mizar: You are right that I was being careless: actually I was implicitly using the following fact, which I think is true but I cannot prove. 


**Fact?** Every 2-dimensional subspace of $\ell^q$ is isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_q)$.

Comment: If the "Fact?" is true, assuming by contradiction that a linear isometry $J\colon \ell^p\to\ell^q$ exists, and setting 
$$E_p=\mathrm{span}(e_1, e_2)\subset\ell^p,$$
$$E_q=J(E_p),$$
we have an induced isometry of $E_p$ onto $E_q$. Now $E_p$ is isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_p)$ and, **if** the "Fact?" is true, $E_q$ is isometric to $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_q)$. We can then proceed to prove that an isometry of $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_p)$ onto $(\mathbb{R}^2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_q)$ cannot exist.

Comment: I'm not sure the "fact" is true. For instance over the reals,  $\ell_2^2$ embeds isometrically in $\ell_4^6$. This is shown in Proposition 18, Chapter 21 of the *Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces*, vol 1. So, $\ell_4$ contains a two-dimensional subspace isometric to $\ell_2^2$. Of course, $\ell_2^2$ is not isometric to $\ell_4^2$. (Superscripts are dimensions.)

Comment: In fact, wouldn't it follow from Dvoretzky's Theorem ($\ell_2$ is finitely representable in every infinite-dimensional Banach space), that if all two-dimensional subspaces of an infinite-dimensional $X$ were isometric, then they are are in fact isometric to $\ell_2^2$ (and thus $X$ is isometric to $\ell_2$)?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Unfortunately I don't know any of those tools you are mentioning. Of course if the "Fact" is false then this idea of reducing the problem to the two dimensional case is not applicable (or at least not so easily). I'm going to mention it in my post